# ?: in old version of PHP causing parse error

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I've been using the SimpleImage class for image manipulation but it doesn't work on one particular site the version of PHP on the server is 5.1.6 - so six years old

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in…

the lines in question which cause the error being

```
$height = $height ?: $width; 
$quality = $quality ?: $this->quality;
$filename = $filename ?: $this->filename;
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: $height = $height ? $width : $width;

Comment: `$height = $height ? $height : $width;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're missing an argument in your ternary operator, it should be this syntax:

```
$height = $height ? $height : $width;
$quality = $quality ? $quality : $this->quality;
$filename = $filename ? $filename : $this->filename;
```

There should be 2 variables following the ? symbol, separated by a : symbol.
The first variable is what is set if the condition (before the ?) is true. 
The second variable is what is set if the condition is false.

EDIT:

The syntax `?:` is only available since PHP version 5.3, make sure you're running php 5.3 or greater.

Comment: @user2864740 It is the ternary operator, just a shorthand for a common use of it

Comment: Didn't realise there was a shorthand version of it until now! I still prefer the longer syntax for readability.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was sure it was some sort of shorthand issue I wasn't aware of but searching for "?:" wasn't bringing up any pages of use.

Answer (score 4):

The ternary operator shorthand `$val1 ?: $val2` was [introduced in PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and is identical to `$val1 ? $val1 : $val2`